# Define the events in order to use Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability

The exercise I'm trying to solve using Bayes Theorem says: suppose you have a urn 1 with two balls: one white, one black, and a urn 2 with two black balls and two white balls. You pick randomly two balls, one at a time, from urn 2 and transfer them to urn 1. Then you pick randomly a ball from urn 1. What is the probability that the chosen ball from urn 1 is white? What is the probability that at least one white ball had been transferred?

My problem here is, how to define the events so I can use Bayes Theorem.

A = "the ball picked from urn 2 is white"
$$ 
P(A)=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

I think that is the answer of the second question (the probability that at least one white ball had been transferred).

B = "the ball picked from urn 1 is white"
$$
P(B)=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Then $P(B|A)$ would be the probability of picking a white ball from urn 1 after picking a white ball in urn 2. Hence:

$$
P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B)P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

But I'm not sure that's the correct result... anyway, from here I understand that the Bayes Theorem must use a partition of events, and now I'm not sure what partitions should I use. Any thought will be appreciated.

Comment: One way to address the last question is to observe that the only way to *avoid* transferring a white ball at any point is to transfer the two black balls from Urn $2$ to Urn $1$, and then to transfer one of the three black balls from Urn $1$ back to Urn $2$.  You simply need to compute the joint probability of these two events; if you denote them by $A$ and $B$, respectively, you are looking for $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B \mid A)$.  Your desired probability is then $1-P(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the events should be

- $X$: The number of white balls drawn from Urn 2; the three possible outcomes 2,1, and 0 define the partition you need.
- $B$: The ball drawn from Urn 1 is white; this is the conditioning event.

The probabilities we are after are then $P(B)$ and $P(X=1|B)+ P(X=2|B)$.

Regarding the former, we use the law of total probability to say that
$$P(B) = P(B|X=2)P(X=2) + P(B|X=1) P(X=1) +P(B|X=0)P(X=0).$$

Where

$$P(X=2) = 1/4$$
$$P(X=1) = 1/2$$
$$P(X=0) = 1/4$$
and where

$$P(B|X=n) = \frac{1+n}{4}$$
(If I have transferred $n$ white balls, I have $n+1$ white balls in a total of $4$.)

Once you have these, you can use Bayes' theorem to find $P(X=n|B)$ and the result:

$$P(X=1\vee X=2|B) = 1-P(X=0|B) = 1- \frac{P(B|X=0)P(X=0) }{P(B)};$$

where we have used the fact that $X=n$ is a partition: the probabilities of the events $X=1\vee X=2$ and $X=0$ sum to one
$$P(X=1\vee X=2|B) + P(X=0|B) =1.$$

Note that you don't need to observe this and you can directly compute:
$$P(X=1\vee X=2|B) = \frac{P(B|X=1)P(X=1) + P(B|X=2)P(X=2) }{P(B)};$$
where we have used the fact that $P(X=1\wedge X=2) =0$. The result will be the same.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I got to one result by calculating P(B) and $P(X_n | B)$ but a question, why do I have to calculate $P(X_1 \vee X_2 | B)$ ? Didn't quite follow that last part. Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated my answer. The question asks what is the probability of having transferred at least one white ball (so $X=1$ OR $X=2$) given that I have drawn a white ball from urn 1 (so $B$). Thus, we are looking for $P(X=1\vee X=2|B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the following events:

$A$ -- $2$ white balls were picked from box 2,

$B$ -- $2$ black balls were picked from box 2,

$C$ -- $1$ white and $1$ black ball picked from box 2.

Then, $P(A) = 1/4, P(B)=1/4, P(C)=1/2$.

Furthermore, conditional probabilities of selecting a white ball from box $1$ after the transfer are: $P(W|A) = 3/4, P(W|B)=1/4, P(W|C)=1/2.$

Then, $P(W)= (|)P(A)+ P(|)P(B)+(|)P(C)=1/2,$ which answers the first question.

Let $D$ be the event that "at least one white ball was transferred from to box $1$. Then $D^c$ is the event that two black balls were transferred, so $P(D^c)=1/4$.

According to the Bayes' theorem: $P(D^c|W) = P(W|D^c)P(D^c)/P(W) = (1/4 \times 1/4)/(1/2)=1/8.
$

Finally, $P(D|W) = 1-P(D^c|W)= 7/8.$

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. To understand better, what does W stand for, selecting a white ball in box 1?

Comment: Yes, $W$ is the event that a white ball is selected from box $1$.

Comment: Just to make it clear(er) --   is the event that a white ball is selected from box $1$ after the balls were transferred to it from box $2$.